# Choosing the right Relay for the mission

Tags: avr, relay, safety

I am building new project, which I will power up the water tank heater from my smartphone.
I have few safety though I want to ask here to get your opinion..

I am going to use AVR to run a relay, that will be connected to the main AC line.
my heater takes about 11-12Amp on 240VAC.

1. Which relay should I use? SSR or mechanical? I looked into these 2:

   - [SSR-25DA](http://www.multice.com/bp/Solid%20State%20Relay/SSR-25DA.htm)
   - [Relay SPDT Sealed - 20A](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10924)

   I think the mechanical is better because I have physical disconnection, but I am afraid of "jumps" on the mechanical device (like de-bounce and such). what do you think will be better here?
2. Relay mount - if I am going to use the mechanical T9A relay, how do you think I should mount it? it has no mount, maybe I will try to use terminal block like this to connect the legs:

[image: Terminal Block]

Comment: I inlined the links and image for you. You'll be able to do the same with enough rep, just keep at it. :)

Comment: Can you find a DPDT relay with spade connectors? Then you can use something like [insulation sleeve for spade connector](http://www.conrad-electronic.co.uk/ce/en/product/735529/Soft-PVC-insulation-sleeve-for-spade-connector-63-mm-Soft-PVC-Transparent;jsessionid=5B30FB5A2FDF03CAC16DF10E547AF730.ASTPCEN20?ref=list) over the connectors to make it safer. Remember, sleeve on *before* crimping spade connector with a purpose-made crimping tool. And a fuse. **Disclaimer** I am not an electrician.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to think about as you proceed.

- SSR drops \$1.6V\$, according to your link. At \$12A\$, you are \$\approx 20W\$ dissipation with the SSR. I'd plan for even more dissipation to be safer. You need to consider an attached heat sink for it.
- EMR relays can come powered either by the AC line voltage (using a shading pole or shorted turn embedded into one end of the armature) or some DC voltage. You could consider using an AC relay that operates from 240VAC and including a MOC3023 or MOC3063 (one triggers at the zero crossing, the other doesn't care) opto in order to turn it on safely. This moves the relay power requirement to your line instead of your DC supply for the AVR, though you still need 5mA for the opto. But the coil dissipation for the EMR you listed is 0.9W. And any power supply you use for your micro system will have to include that. That's a lot, by comparison. So "shifting the load" may offer an advantage worth considering.
- If you want to get fancy (and since you are including a micro, you can do that), you could consider the combined use of an SSR and EMR. The SSR is triggered first and operates for some designated period of time while you then activate the EMR and wait for it to be engaged. Then drop out the SSR, leaving the EMR handling the load. A similar process turns things off, as well. You may be able to consider avoiding the heat sink on the SSR this way, if you can assure yourself that you won't overheat it. (Or you can get fancy and possibly even include a bimetal switch taken from a fish tank heater, for example, that will open if things get hot -- which may be smaller than the heat sink.) But another advantage is that the contacts on the EMR won't be subjected to arcing and so will probably last longer, as well. This is called a "hybrid" relay. You can google it. You will have to carefully consider your situation if you do this, though. It has advantages and disadvantages.
- A relay I chose looked like this: [JQX-40F 1Z 40A 110VAC](http://www.ebay.com/itm/JQX-40F-1Z-40A-110VAC-Coil-PCB-Power-Relay-/370724511922?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5650e720b2). But I'm working with 110VAC here. But that provides another kind of mounting you might look for.

Just some thoughts to consider. Since you will be putting this into a proto box of some kind, mounting is probably best left to your ingenuity.

RESPONSE NOTES:

- The EMR you linked specs \$\approx 1W\$ to hold it engaged. Actually, within spec, it could even be slightly more. At \$5V\$, that's \$200mA\$. Your DC power supply will need to support that load, plus whatever else is required of your DC supply. By comparison, a MOC3023 requires \$5mA\$ to operate an AC relay coil, which itself draws its power from the line and itself only uses perhaps \$30mW\$. It's lower power all around. I'm not telling you to use one. Use what you feel is best. I'm just suggesting an alternative to consider.
- Don't use the SSR to power the EMR. I was offering a thought about using an SSR in parallel to an EMR. For more details, I suggest you google "hybrid relay" and see what comes up. In this case, you protect the mechanical contacts of the EMR using an SSR. There are some nice youtube videos illustrating the elimination of arcing under power using this method. But since what I wrote wasn't clear, I recommend you avoid this idea for now.

ADDITIONAL RESPONSE NOTE:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb19AD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That relay you chose: doesn't it have a 110VAC *coil*? So the OP would need a relay to activate the relay.

Comment: I mentioned the MOC302x and MOC306x devices in my note for exactly that purpose. Been there, done that. The coil current is extremely tiny to operate those, too. On the order of \$2M\Omega\$ loading to the 110VAC line.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I am a bit confused now :).. just a SSR will not be good for me, you are right, because of the 20W leakage, so it looks like i need to go with the EMR. i did not understood your 2 and 3 sections, why should i use SSR or MOC30xx to power the EMR? can't i just power it with transistor connected to digital pin out from my IC? also, can you please give your opinion about the de-bounce of the EMR?

Comment: See RESPONSE NOTES above.

Comment: I think i got your idea with the parallel SSR. Is your idea is to use SSE in parallel to EMR, power the SSR, wait 1 second, power the coil for the EMR, wait 1 sec, close SSR. this whole operation is to eliminate the arc on the mechanical switch, right? brilliant! But is it really necessary? i want to do it as small as i can BUT don't want to skip safety. About the MOC, I am not really familiar with those Optocouplers, so I need to read more on that, but your main idea is to use 240V Relay with 240AC coil, which powered by the MOC, which powered from AVR, right?

Comment: About the MOC idea - is it only to save power? to reduce the 1W to 30mW? if so, doesn't the AC coil will take about 1W as well? so i am saving on the 5V adapter, but spending on the main line power? also, 2 SPST EMR relays takes ~400mA and i want to use 5V 1A Adapter.

Comment: Well, it's more like power the SSR for 1 second, but also start the EMR almost immediately, too. It will engage in less than 1 second and you can drop out the SSR, then. Whether all that trouble is necessary depends on what you consider important. My system goes into a wall where it isn't accessible and absolute lowest power dissipation plus preventative measures against contact wear on the EMR are of high priority. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: The MOC's are dirt cheap -- get them on ebay for nothing, almost. They basically come in increasingly higher voltage tolerances and in zero-cross vs random. You want something at the 400VAC or better. I think the MOC3023 is random, the MOC3063 is zero-cross, and both are rated high enough. But you should verify all that.

Comment: No, the AC relay actually is about \$2M\Omega\$. If you compute the \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$ for the power, you will find that it really is about \$30mW\$ for the entire coil. This is better than \$1W\$. They use a lot of really fine wire and are pretty impressive. Depending on other requirements, you might greatly lower your DC supply requirements, opening up more options for you to consider. Going from a couple of watts to \$100mW\$ can make a surprising difference in your available choices.

Comment: Thanks jonk, so just to be sure, the SSR is to prevent the electric ark and get the EMR life longer, right? (and of course not using the SSR alone due to the heatting issue). I didn't understood your last sentence "absolute lowest power dissipation plus preventative measures against contact wear on the EMR are of high priority" so I am asking again.. sorry..

Comment: jonk, doesn't the SSR voltage leakage going to be an issue? Even if it is in parallel to the EMR it still going to get some voltage flow through it, so the heater will get small amount of power, no?

Comment: When I place a "system" into the wall, lower dissipation is better. I don't want "warm spots" in a wall. Cold is good. So lowest activated power is a "good thing." Separately, the EMR does "make/break" at random points in the AC cycle. But the SSR switches at zero-cross. So if you switch the SSR first, and it drops \$1.6V\$ under load, there will only be a couple of volts across the EMR contacts when they switch in (or out.) That's nicer for the EMR contacts than closing with voltages that may be as high as \$340V\$.

Comment: Thanks, one last question about the SSR, I read in the datasheet that if the SSR is off, it still forwarding some small amount of power, so even if the SSR is off, the heater will small amount of power on the AC, isn't it bad for the heater, and isn't it not efficient solution?

Comment: I think someone already mentioned "snubbers" to you. That's the "small amount of power." It's pretty small and doesn't impact efficiency here. It's not going to be bad for any massive water heater I've seen. Mostly, this snubber leakage is about being a shock hazard when you work around it. It means you should be careful, yourself.

Comment: Thanks, so i will try the following schematic: 2x SPST EMR + 1x SSR. on power request -> 1 EMR will contact (no power on the AC yet - the 2nd line opened.), contact SSR, contact 2nd EMR (the one with the SSR protection), discontact the SSR. on power off will do the same in reverse (SSR - 2nd EMR, 1st EMR). the box is outside the wall, next to the phisycal heater switch, so i think it will be good enough, right? I do not need any MOC or any other switching device (beside transistors and resistors of course..). what is your opinion? Thanks Again!

Comment: No, I was thinking more like my "ADDITIONAL RESPONSE NOTE" above in the answer. Micro activates the SSR, waits 10ms or so, activates EMR, waits 500ms, deactivates SSR... holds.... then to turn off, activates SSR again, waits 10ms, deactivates EMR, waits 500ms, deactivates SSR... done.

Comment: Got it. I will do like you said, I think it is very good idea. The only change is that i will not use the MOC part, and i will use 5V relay instead AC-AC EMR, i have 5V 1A adapter that should be fine with the 200mA of the 5V coil EMR. The main thing is that i already have those 2 5V EMRs. But just to under stand it better, I see you are using the MOC and i understood that the main reason is to be able to run AC-AC EMRs, is there any reason to do it beside power consumption on the 5V line?

Comment: By MOC - you said "zero-cross vs random" , I tried to Google it and I find some info, but to be sure that I understood it right, the random cross, is that "snubbers" we talked about, right? so zero-cross will not have this "snubbers" and no small voltage will forwarded when the switch is off? Thanks.

Comment: A zero-cross SSR or opto-TRIAC only triggers when the AC voltage goes through zero voltage. If you try and fire it earlier, it waits. A random-fire SSR (rare) or opto-TRIAC triggers when you trigger it and doesn't wait. The snubber issue is separate. I think most SSRs have snubbers. Again, the main worry is that you don't touch that side of the SSR when it is attached to the hot wires. Zero-cross and snubbers have pretty much nothing at all to do with each other. They exist for completely different purposes.

Comment: Got it, so I don't see any reason to use zero-cross or random than the other one, it is ok to wait for the Sin wave to cross the Zero, if I got it correctly.

Comment: You won't have much choice about it, regarding the SSR. I think most do zero-cross switching. Because it's the right thing to do for most uses. EMRs are pretty much never zero-cross (I don't know of one that does, or how it might do it.) Make sure you feel certain of what and why about these things before you act.

Comment: I understand the zero-crossing thing, but I am not sure I understood why doe's it matter at all, I am not familiar with device that "know" or "want" to start on AC when the wave crossing the zero, but I will try to read about it on-line. I have some shopping to do now (SSR, EMRs, chips...) :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a home water heater, surely it has a thermostat which already controls a relay or solid-state switch for the heater. Why not use your AVR to switch or otherwise intervene with the thermostat circuit?

Comment: I don't want to play with the boiler itself.. not there yet.. just learning for now :)